# encoding в xgboost python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, xgboost

Добрый день, коллеги!
загружаю файл

```
df = read_table('TQq.txt', sep = '\t', encoding='utf_8', decimal='.')
```

получаю нормальные русские заголовки и текст в таблице.
Далее анализ

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=91)
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix( X_train, label=y_train)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix( X_test, label=y_test)
param = {'bst:max_depth':3, 'bst:eta':0.1, 'silent':1, 'objective':'binary:logistic', 'eval_metric' : 'map', 'seed' : 1 }
param['nthread'] = 40
evallist  = [(dtest,'test'), (dtrain,'train')]
num_round = 10
bst = xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_round, evallist)
```

И при попытке получить важность факторов получаю

```
xgb.plot_importance(bst)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в каком месте необходимо сделать encoding еще?
да, кодировку cp1251 я тоже делал, тот же результат

Comment: Стандартный шрифт не поддерживает кириллицу, может помочь смена шрифта: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960463/non-ascii-characters-in-matplotlib. Внутри xgboost используется matplotlib для графиков.

Comment: Спасибо, Илья, помогло
И да, скорее стоило указать matplotlib , а не xgboost